# MariaDB is not listening on port 3306

Tags: mysql, port, mariadb

I have MariaDB server running on Debian 9. Problem is that if I run `netstat -anp | grep 3306` nothing shows, but MariaDB server is running, I can connect to it via `mysql` command.

MariaDB config:

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
port = 3306
skip-networking
```

Comment: I believe it needs to be `bind_address`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mysql` by default connects via unix sockets when `localhost` is used as the server.

If you want your server to be available via TCP/IP you need to remove the `skip-networking` directive from your config (and restart the service).